# Strange syntax error with flutter_localizations and intl

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Recently (today) I tried to create an app for web and desktop with Flutter and wanted it to be in multiple languages (English, French, Arabic, Dutch...) so I looked at [Flutter's tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) and followed every steps it had. And just after finishing the last step I had it working ! I could add text in, English in the app_en.arb file and in any other language in app_fr.arb by example. When I hot reloaded/restarted my app the Dart files it generates are rebuilt. But now when I do that I have an error that I couldn't find anywhere else on Internet:

```
Exception: Found syntax errors.
```

And the dart files for localization weren't rebuilt. Now I must use the

```
flutter gen-l10n
```

command to rebuild my language files.

Note:
Here's my flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.7.0-10.0.pre.33, on Fedora Linux 37 (Workstation Edition) 6.0.12-300.fc37.x86_64, locale fr_FR.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.7.0-10.0.pre.33 on channel master at /home/theskyblockman/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cee3e6cc3d (il y a 8 heures), 2022-12-17 04:03:24 -0500
    • Engine revision b107699980
    • Dart version 3.0.0 (build 3.0.0-35.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.20.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/theskyblockman/Android/Sdk/
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /home/theskyblockman/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/213.7172.25.2113.9014738/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
    • cmake version 3.16.3
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /home/theskyblockman/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/213.7172.25.2113.9014738
    • Flutter plugin version 71.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 213.7433
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.2)
    • IntelliJ at /home/theskyblockman/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/222.4459.24
    • Flutter plugin version 71.0.5
    • Dart plugin version 222.4459.16

[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.0)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.54.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Fedora Linux 37 (Workstation Edition) 6.0.12-300.fc37.x86_64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 110.0.5464.2 dev

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's me again, this looked like a PATH problem in my case. Now that I restarted my computer I don't have the error anymore, I should have checked that before. But as I never saw this error before you should check other things like dependencies versions or your Dart and Flutter SDKs, I am not sure about how it happened so restart your computer and check a lot of things could help fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this error had appeared after I renamed the folder where project files was. I fixed all paths with old folder name, but the error was still persist. `flutter clean` didn't help.

Then in folder named `.idea` I found few files (`.xml` and `.iml` extensions) that contained the old folder's name. After I fixed it the error was gone. Hope will help.

Comment: Great advice ! I think that if someone else encounters this problem this could probably help them. But in my case I was using VSCode so the .idea folder does not exist. This shows that this error message could mean a lot of things could have gone wrong.

Comment: @theskyblockman hi! The thing is that I'm using VSCode too ;) and I don't know why, but the `.idea` folder is present there ) my be this is because I used `verygood_cli` tool to create project.